# What is the difference between "is contained" and "has contained"?

Tags: american-english

What is the difference between the sentences below?

> The eckofarmer is contained in a 13 meter long module
>
> The eckofarmer has contained in a 13 meter long module

I think that the second sentence needs a direct or indirect adjective. That is true?

Comment: The second sentence doesn't make sense. Has contained what?

Comment: Forgive me if this sounds off-topic; but what is an *eckofarmer*?

Comment: @Aravind Suresh I was just about to ask that, but less politely!

Answer (score 1):

> The eckofarmer is contained in a 13-meter long module.

means either one of the following:

1. that the eckofarmer is placed inside a 13-meter long module,
2. that an organism (e.g., a pathogen) called "the eckofarmer" has been captured and placed in a 13-meter long module, in order to prevent it from escaping.

> The eckofarmer has contained in a 13-meter long module.

is an ungrammatical sentence. A variation:

> The eckofarmer has contained *something* in a 13-meter long module.

This means that "the eckofarmer" has captured something and imprisoned it in a 13-meter long module.

Yet another variation:

> The eckofarmer has *been* contained in a 13-meter long module.

This means that the eckofarmer itself has been captured and placed in such a module.

Remember that the meanings of these sentences may change according to the definition of the subject. It might be useful to know what "the eckofarmer" is.

Comment: Isn't your option 2 just a more specific instance of option 1? What about option 3, the eckofarmer was there first and a module was built around it.